# How to check if iframe is loaded by itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe that loads what a user requests. However, I need to make sure that the iframe does not load itself and is instead redirected to a default site.

The process has to be dynamic and work on any page, as I have multiple pages doing this, and custom code for each site wouldn't be practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are on the same domain as your parent, you can use `parent`. Add to the documents having iframes:

```
$(function() {

    // Check if you are in an iframe, otherwise parent == self,
    // and the next check will always return true.
    function inIframe () {
        try {
            return window.self !== window.top;
        } catch (e) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Check if parent.url == self.url.
    function sameAsParent() {
        try {
            return parent.window.document.location.toString() === window.document.location.toString());
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (inIframe() && sameAsParent()) {
        // You are being loaded by yourself! Redirect!
        window.location.href = 'http://some-redirect-url.com'
    }

});
```